# Динамическое обновление состояния и положения движущихся объектов в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, gui, controller, fxml

Подскажите, что использовать для отображения хаотично движущихся точек, меняющих цвет в JavaFX ?
Количество точек может быть разным (параметр). Цвет точек передает принадлежность к определенному  классу (их всего 3).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока есть такой набросок:

```
this.allPoints = (ObservableList<CoquilleBille>) model.getAllPoints();
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask tTask = new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            for (CoquilleBille cb : allPoints)
            {
                String state = cb.getIndividual().getClass().getSimpleName();
                double coordX = cb.getPosition().getX();
                double coordY = cb.getPosition().getY();

                Dot point = new Dot(coordX, coordY);

                if (state.equals("Recovered")) { point.changeColor("#ff1f40"); }
                if (state.equals("Sick")) { point.changeColor("#ffa07a"); }
            }
        }            
    };
```

И далее планирую делать апдейт картинки 30 раз в секунду

```
timer.schedule(tTask, 0, 33);
```

Но не могу понять как это имплементировать в контроллере, чтобы оно вписалось в fxml

```xml
<AnchorPane layoutX="31.0" layoutY="232.0" prefHeight="323.0" prefWidth="460.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff;">
     <children>
        <Circle fx:id="dot1" centerX="30.0" centerY="30.0" fill="#ff1f40" radius="2.0" stroke="#ff1f40" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle centerX="50.0" centerY="50.0" fill="ffa07a" radius="2.0" stroke="ffa07a" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fx:id="dot" centerX="100.0" centerY="100.0" fill="#14902b" radius="2.0" stroke="#14902b" strokeType="INSIDE" />
     </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Пока там нарисованы 3 круга разных цветов, но мне то нужно, чтобы их можно было отрисовывать нефиксированное количество, плюс передавать параметры цвета сюда.

Comment: В fxml создаете пустой контейнер (пусть будет тот же AnchorPane), а в коде динамически создаете круги (просто `new Circle(тут какие-то параметры)`), добавляете их как детей к AnchorPane.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, @insolor!!

А как обратиться к этому AnchorPane если, скажем, он получил fx:id="panel" ?

Comment: В контроллере объявляете его как `@FXML AnchorPane panel;` после этого в контроллере к этому полю обращаетесь.

Comment: Cпасибо! сработало!
Получилось отобразить первоначальное положение точек и их цвета с помощью метода initialize().
Осталось разобраться как все это отображать в движении с помощью таймера.

Comment: @pinkiBet Есть ещё варианты использовать Task и Platform. Последний вариант уродует код, но он рабочий.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такой вариант,он не связан с вашим кодом, но может быть вам интересен как возможный инструмент. :

```
public class SlideLiveTimer extends Task<Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {

        int counts = 0;
        while (counts<100){
            Thread.sleep(105);
            counts++;
        }

        SlideModalError.hideStatus.play();
        SlideModalError.showsStatus = false;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Вызов из другого класса :

```
SlideLiveTimer slt = new SlideLiveTimer();
Thread thread = new Thread(slt);
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

*В данном примере, спустя какое-то время скрывается объект X.*

Вам нужно будет в ваш класс, расширяемый "таском" запихнуть контроллер(передать в конструкторе). Затем в цикле выполнять операции. Изменения связанные с GUI необходимо оборачивать в

```
Platform.runLater(()->{
                // ВАш КОД
                 });
```

Передаваемые параметры (в данном случае координаты, должны быть final(Перед вызовом Platform). Безопасность здесь рекомендовать не могу, поскольку возможен рассинхрон.

Answer (score 0):

Многопоточность препод сказал не делать, мол нам пока будет сложно синхронизировать потоки (эта симуляция делается небольшой группой студентов второкурсников )). Получается, в ней несколько таймеров, работающих параллельно из разных классов на одном потоке.
Пока реализовала с помощью Timeline, вроде работает.
Но, подозреваю, вероятно в последствии это придется переделать, поэтому большое спасибо за все идеи, что вы здесь предложили, возможно я вернусь к ним.